Trigger an AWS Code Deploy from an API call
I am trying to create a deployment strategy when the code deploy should start deploying the application when it receives a trigger from an API call. I have an application which onboards a user, where the user actually signs up and once the user clicks on submit, this should trigger the code deploy and deploy  the application on the environment.
